# Upload Single File Using Element UI on VueJS

Tags: css, vue.js, element-ui

I have a question about uploading an image on vuejs using elementUI `el-upload`. I want to hiding the selected box ( + ) after select one image.

[image]

I have to follow the instructions step by step on this site https://programmersought.com/article/59531832236/;jsessionid=6B629FE55DAE317A6E98B9049DAAEECC , but unfortunatelly i have not been able to implement it
Could everyone here to help me to solve this problem ?
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manage it your self to keeping tracking whether you selected something:

```
<div id="app">
<el-upload
  action="#"
  list-type="picture-card"
  :auto-upload="false"
  :on-change="toggleUpload" 
  :on-remove="toggleUpload"   
  :class="{ hideUpload: !showUpload }" >
    <i slot="default" class="el-icon-plus"></i>
    <div slot="file" slot-scope="{file}">
      <img
        class="el-upload-list__item-thumbnail"
        :src="file.url" alt=""
      >
    </div>
</el-upload>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        showUpload: true
      };
    },
    methods: {
      toggleUpload() {
        this.showUpload = !this.showUpload
      },
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

CSS

```
.hideUpload > div {
  display: none;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/rNxeKeY

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to eliminate the area that appears after selecting an image, this simple css code will work.

```
<style>
.el-upload-list > .is-success + * {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```